# Html Audio Player Multiple Instance Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to use multiple instances of this player : https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Custom-HTML5-Audio-Player-with-jQuery-CSS.html

I have duplicated and renamed all html selectors and the corresponding javascript selectors such as #play2, #audio-player2 etc. for second one. But both instances are not working properly. When clicked play or next button of first one the second one also interacts.  Here is my demo:https://www.ichastaliklari.com/audio/

```js
var audio;

//Hide Pause
$('#pause').hide();

initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    
    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('media/'+ song);
    
    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist').text(artist);
    $('.title').text(title);
    
    //Insert song cover
    $('img.cover').attr('src','images/covers/'+cover);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}

//Play button
$('#play').click(function(){
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    showDuration();
});

//Pause button
$('#pause').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#pause').hide();
});

//Stop button
$('#stop').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});

//Next button
$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Prev button
$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Playlist song click
$('#playlist li').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    initAudio($(this));
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Volume control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});

//Time/Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate',function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt(audio.currentTime / 60) % 60;
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':'+ s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
    });
}


/*******************************second instance*********************************/
var audio;

//Hide Pause
$('#pause2').hide();

initAudio($('#playlist2 li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    
    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('media/'+ song);
    
    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist').text(artist);
    $('.title').text(title);
    
    //Insert song cover
    $('img.cover').attr('src','images/covers/'+cover);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}

//Play button
$('#play2').click(function(){
    audio.play();
    $('#play2').hide();
    $('#pause2').show();
    showDuration();
});

//Pause button
$('#pause2').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    $('#play2').show();
    $('#pause2').hide();
});

//Stop button
$('#stop2').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});

//Next button
$('#next2').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist2 li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist2 li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Prev button
$('#prev2').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist2 li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist2 li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Playlist song click
$('#playlist2 li').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    initAudio($(this));
    $('#play2').hide();
    $('#pause2').show();
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Volume control
$('#volume2').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});

//Time/Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate',function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt(audio.currentTime / 60) % 60;
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration2').html(m + ':'+ s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress2').css('width',value+'%');
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #665266; /* Old browsers */
}

.clearfix { clear: both; }

.container {
  width: 330px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #1F1C2C 10%, #928DAB 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #1F1C2C 10%, #928DAB 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #1F1C2C 10%, #928DAB 90%); /* IE10 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #1F1C2C 10%, #928DAB 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1F1C2C 10%, #928DAB 90%); /* W3C */
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 150px auto;
  border-radius: 13px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -8px #333;
}

#audio-image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#audio-image .cover { width: 100%; }

#audio-info { text-align: center; }

#audio-info .artist { font-weight: bold; }

input#volume {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input#volume::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 background:url(../images/knob.png) no-repeat;
 height:12px;
 width:12px;
}

#buttons {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  margin-left: 23px;
  overflow: auto;
}

button#play {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/play.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

button#pause {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/pause.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

button#stop {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/stop.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

button#prev {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button#next {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/next.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#tracker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress-bar {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url(../images/progress_bg.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

#progress {
  background: url(../images/progress.png) no-repeat;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#playlist { list-style: none; }

#playlist li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

#playlist li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #666;
}


#audio-image2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#audio-image2 .cover { width: 100%; }

#audio-info2 { text-align: center; }

#audio-info2 .artist { font-weight: bold; }

input#volume2 {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input#volume2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance:none !important;
 background:url(../images/knob.png) no-repeat;
 height:12px;
 width:12px;
}

#buttons2 {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  margin-left: 23px;
  overflow: auto;
}

button#play2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/play.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

button#pause2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/pause.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

button#stop2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/stop.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

button#prev2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button#next2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/next.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#tracker2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress-bar2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  background: url(../images/progress_bg.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
}

#progress2 {
  background: url(../images/progress.png) no-repeat;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#duration2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#playlist2 { list-style: none; }

#playlist2 li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

#playlist2 li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="display:flex;">
<div class="container">
  <div id="audio-image"> <img class="cover"> </div>
  <div id="audio-player">
    <div id="audio-info"> <span class="artist"></span> - <span class="title"></span> </div>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="4">
    <br>
    <div id="buttons"> <span>
      <button id="prev"></button>
      <button id="play"></button>
      <button id="pause"></button>
      <button id="stop"></button>
      <button id="next"></button>
      </span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="tracker">
      <div id="progress-bar"> <span id="progress"></span> </div>
      <span id="duration">0:00</span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <ul id="playlist" class="hidden">
      <li song="Sample.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Sample.mp3</li>
      <li song="sound1.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="sound1">sound1.mp3</li>
      <li song="sound2.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="sound2">sound2.mp3</li>
      <li song="80s_vibe.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="80s_vibe">80s_vibe.mp3</li>
      <li song="running_out.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="running_out">running_out.mp3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="audio-image2"> <img class="cover"> </div>
  <div id="audio-player2">
    <div id="audio-info2"> <span class="artist"></span> - <span class="title"></span> </div>
    <input id="volume2" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="4">
    <br>
    <div id="buttons2"> <span>
      <button id="prev2"></button>
      <button id="play2"></button>
      <button id="pause2"></button>
      <button id="stop2"></button>
      <button id="next2"></button>
      </span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="tracker">
      <div id="progress-bar2"> <span id="progress2"></span> </div>
      <span id="duration2">0:00</span> </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <ul id="playlist2" class="hidden">
      <li song="Sample.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Linkin Park">Sample.mp3</li>
      <li song="sound1.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="sound1">sound1.mp3</li>
      <li song="sound2.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="sound2">sound2.mp3</li>
      <li song="80s_vibe.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="80s_vibe">80s_vibe.mp3</li>
      <li song="running_out.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="running_out">running_out.mp3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I think I should do some work with js but I do not know what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *When clicked play or next button of first one the second one also interacts.* - is that *also* or *instead*?  If you click the second one what happens to the first?   You have a *single* `var audio` variable (the second should give you a warning in your IDE), so it's unclear how you would expect it to handle two objects.   Rewrite your entire js without any #ID (using IDs is a crutch that you now need to get out from under) - use `this` inside `function xx() {` event handlers and relative DOM navigation, eg `$(this).closest(".container").find(".next")`

Comment: Thanks for answer I have attached a demo link in my message you can see problem there: https://www.ichastaliklari.com/audio/ when clicking second one both are being affected.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved changing almost all selectors like showDuration, showDuration2,auido,auio2 etc. here is my working js.

```html
var audio;
//Hide Pause
$('#pause').hide();

initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    
    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('media/'+ song);
    
    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist').text(artist);
    $('.title').text(title);
    
    //Insert song cover
    $('img.cover').attr('src','images/covers/'+cover);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}

//Play button
$('#play').click(function(){
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    showDuration();
});

//Pause button
$('#pause').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#pause').hide();
});

//Stop button
$('#stop').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});

//Next button
$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Prev button
$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Playlist song click
$('#playlist li').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    initAudio($(this));
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Volume control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});

//Time/Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate',function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt(audio.currentTime / 60) % 60;
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':'+ s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
    });
}


/*******************************second instance*********************************/
var audio2;
//Hide Pause
$('#pause2').hide();

initAudio2($('#playlist2 li:first-child'));

function initAudio2(element){
    var song2 = element.attr('song2');
    var title2 = element.text();
    var cover2 = element.attr('cover2');
    var artist2 = element.attr('artist2');
    
    //Create audio object
    audio2 = new Audio('media/'+ song2 );
    
    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist2').text(artist2 );
    $('.title2').text(title2);
    
    //Insert song cover
    $('img.cover2').attr('src','images/covers/'+cover2);
    
    $('#playlist2 li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');
}

//Play button
$('#play2').click(function(){
    audio2.play();
    $('#play2').hide();
    $('#pause2').show();
    showDuration2();
});

//Pause button
$('#pause2').click(function(){
    audio2 .pause();
    $('#play2').show();
    $('#pause2').hide();
});

//Stop button
$('#stop2').click(function(){
    audio2 .pause();
    audio2 .currentTime = 0;
});

//Next button
$('#next2').click(function(){
    audio2 .pause();
    var next = $('#playlist2 li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist2 li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio2(next);
    audio2 .play();
    showDuration2();
});

//Prev button
$('#prev2').click(function(){
    audio2 .pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist2 li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist2 li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio2(prev);
    audio2 .play();
    showDuration2();
});

//Playlist song click
$('#playlist2 li').click(function(){
    audio2 .pause();
    initAudio2($(this));
    $('#play2').hide();
    $('#pause2').show();
    audio2 .play();
    showDuration2();
});

//Volume control
$('#volume2').change(function(){
    audio2 .volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
});

//Time/Duration
function showDuration2(){
    $(audio2 ).bind('timeupdate',function(){
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio2 .currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt(audio2 .currentTime / 60) % 60;
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration2').html(m + ':'+ s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio2 .currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio2 .duration) * audio2 .currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress2').css('width',value+'%');
    });
}
```

Comment: you put the JavaScript code in the HTML part of your snippet